# Heroku push error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm attempting to configure my heroku server to upload files to my amazon s3 server.  To do so, I've added the following lines to my `production.rb`

```
s3_options = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config/aws.yml')).symbolize_keys
paperclip_options = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config/paperclip.yml')).symbolize_keys
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => paperclip_options[:s3_host_name],
    :s3_region=> 'us-west-2',
    :s3_credentials => s3_options
}
```

The problem is that when I push the code to heroku, I get the following error.

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen
```

In looking around on google, I've found that this often is caused by referencing relative paths in a configuration file.  However, as far as I can tell, each path is in relation to `Rails.root`.  Can anyone see something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was missing a yml file on my production server.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the set up configuration of AWS-S3 to heroku.

[s3-setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#s3-setup)

[aws-sdk of ruby](http://sessan.hatenablog.com/entry/2012/08/09/171544)